# Is there any way to do genuine pings in PHP? (without exec)

Tags: php, ping, icmp

I'm trying to do actual, genuine ping using ICMP packets, natively in PHP. Right now I'm using exec to run the `ping` command, but you never quite know what it's going to output, which makes it very hard to format the results for web. Different network setups can result in some crazy output. So I wrote my own pinger using socket_create() (with help from the manual comments), but that also doesn't work. Apparently you can't create a raw socket unless your apache server is running as root. That's not a good solution either.

This is a web tool where visitors run a ping on themselves, meaning they visit the page, and my server pings them, and outputs the results. So I can't just open a tcp connection, close it, and use that as a ping, because who knows if the user has any ports open at all.

There is also a pear package for pinging, but ultimately it is just a wrapper for `exec("ping $host");`

I may be stuck with my old code, that uses the system ping command. But I just want to be sure there are no other solutions first. Because I *really* want to do this natively in PHP if I can.

Here is my ping function. It fails with an "unable to create socket [1]" error:

```
function ping_you()
{
$package = "\x08\x00\x19\x2f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x70\x69\x6e\x67";

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);
if ($sock === false)
    {
    echo ">> " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . " <<";
    }

socket_bind($sock,OPERATING_IP);
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec" => 1, "usec" => 0));
socket_connect($sock, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], null);

$start_time = microtime(true);

socket_send($sock, $package, strlen($package), 0);

if(@socket_read($sock, 255))
    {
    $end_time = microtime(true);
    return $end_time - $start_time;
    }
else
    {
    return false;
    }

socket_close($sock);
}
```

Comment: How would I use CURL to ping?

Comment: You have to be root to create raw sockets.

Comment: Yeah... thats why I said that.

Comment: So you know that doing this as *not-root* is impossible, right?

Comment: Then maybe you could change your sudoers file to allow www-data to run a php script as root without a password. Then you could `exec` this script, which would make the ICMP call and return a formatted to your liking message.

Comment: Thats a great idea! I'm new here, how do I up-vote your answer? I don't see any up/down vote buttons.

Comment: It wasn't an answer, just a comment, that's why you can't upvote it. I can post it as an answer though if you wish. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your sudoers file to allow www-data to run a php script as root without a password.

```
www-data ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/path/to/mypingscript
```

Then you could `exec(sudo /path/to/mypingscript)` from your apache php, which would make the ICMP call and return a message formatted to your liking.

**Beware though**, modifying your sudoers file can be dangerous. If you break it you won't be able to run sudo commands, and if you set the permissions wrong this could have bad security consequences.

Comment: Hah turns out I don't have enough reputation to upvote this anyway. But this is a good solution and I'm going to use it. I actually do something just like this so my site can automatically add users that are flooding, to my server's firewall. It didn't even occur to me to use the same system for this though. But I think it's going to work well, thanks!

Comment: As the user who created the question, you have the ability to validate the answer (even if you can't upvote it yet). Try it out before doing so though.